# Parallel algorithm to generate permutations

Tags: permutation

I am trying to generate permutations of strings of length upto 50. This means 50! (50 factorial strings = approx 3.041 * 10^64). I have the following parallel algorithm in mind, considering its not possible to use a single virtual machine or process. I plan to hive of computations to a number of virtual machines:

Say input string is "abcdef"
1) Have a function that removes a request from a common global pool and processes it. A request object consists of two variables: ancestorSequence, remainingCollection
2) Once function is invoked, do the following:
 2a) if remainingCollection has two characters then print this list:
     [ancestorSequence+remainingCollection[0]+remainingCollection[1], ancestorSequence+remainingCollection[1]+remainingCollection[0]
 otherwise do the following
 2b) Create the following requests and add it to the common global pool:
   2b1) (ancestorSequence+remainingCollection[0],remainingCollection without remainingCollection[0])
   2b2) (ancestorSequence+remainingCollection[1],remainingCollection without remainingCollection[1])
   2b3) (ancestorSequence+remainingCollection[2],remainingCollection without remainingCollection[2])
  and so on until
   2bn) (ancestorSequence+remainingCollection[n-1],remainingCollection without remainingCollection[n-1]

We can always optimize by having each function accept multiple such requests. Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: You won't be able to generate/process 50! permutations, thats insane computational power.

Comment: You are right. One commodity machine (3.13 GHz) can iterate over 8! (a string of 8 characters) in 4 seconds. To iterate over permutations of a 9 character string, it would take 1 * 9 VMs, parallely. For 10! it would be 10 * 9 VMs. For n! it would be n!/8! which is O(n!) - not scalable

Comment: We'll have to wait for quantum processors for that ;) Glad if it helped.